# Why does the Perl Twitter API return different results from the normal search on the website?

Tags: perl, twitter

When I search the same query using the Twitter API returning JSON content and using the normal search in twitter website I get different results. The majority of the twits in the JSON response have the same text while in website the twits vary.

Is this happening because in website there are more processing over the response or do I have to set some different parameter?? I already tried to set 'result_type' to 'popular' but in this case, in JSON response, no twits are returned.

ps: Im using the perl module Net::Twitter to access the Twitter API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from the twitter dev discussion forum. The problem is that the search results on Twitter.com are from a relevance-sorted search while the search through Twitter API use the real-time ('classic') search. Only classic search is available from the API right now.

Examples:

```
Twittwer.com -> https://twitter.com/#!/search/Twitter%20API 
would give you relevance sorted results.
Search API   -> https://twitter.com/#!/search/realtime/Twitter%20API 
will give you more exhaustive (well, as exhaustive as the Search API is) results.
```